# How can I insert a value in a determined row of a column in R?

Tags: r, database

My function is given below:

```
MES2 <- function(Base)
{

  cond1 <- grepl("M.E.S", Base$titulo_janela)
  cond2 <- grepl("172.22.5.30", Base$url_destino_N3)
  cond3 <- grepl("mes", Base$atividade_N2)
  cond4 <- grepl("cid/portalmes/", Base$url_destino_N3)
  cond5 <- grepl("novomes", Base$url_destino_N3)
  cond6 <- grepl("AMBEV - MES -", Base$titulo_janela)
  cond7 <- grepl("MES - Manufacturing Execution", Base$titulo_janela)
  cond8 <- grepl("3M_", Base$titulo_janela)

  for (i in 1:length(Base$id)) {
    if (Base$processo_sistema_N1[i] != "iexplore") {
      cond8[i] <- FALSE
    }
  }

  for (k in 1:length(Base$id)) {
    if (cond1[k] == TRUE || cond2[k] == TRUE || cond3[k] == TRUE || cond4[k] == TRUE 
        || cond5[k] == TRUE || cond6[k] == TRUE || cond7[k] == TRUE 
        || cond8[k] == TRUE) {
      Base$processo_sistema_N1[k] <- "MES"
    }
  }

  return(Base)

}
```

The problem is: I want to change the value in a determined row of the column "processo_sistema_N1", but when I run the function on my Base it returns "NA" instead of the word "MES". Do you guys have a clue of what is going wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the problem is that the column `processo_sistema_N1` is a factor instead of characters. In this case, the factor does not contain the level with label "MES", so the result is `NA`.

Comment: and I am sure, the entire code chunk could have been written in 2-3 lines.

Answer (score 0):

before you run the function, add appropriate (future) levels of the column you want to change:
levels(Base$processo_sistema_N1) <- c(levels(Base$processo_sistema_N1), "MES")
Hope that works.